# Most of the url are missing the protocol

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2, sites, icons

Maybe you were trying to fix the other "bug" I've pointed out, but now most of the url for the icons are missing the protocol!

```
{
    "site_type": "main_site",
    "name": "Stack Overflow",
    "logo_url": "//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/logo.png",
    "api_site_parameter": "stackoverflow",
    "site_url": "http://stackoverflow.com",
    "audience": "professional and enthusiast programmers",
    "icon_url": "//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png",
    "aliases": [
        "http://www.stackoverflow.com",
        "http://facebook.stackoverflow.com"
    ],
    "site_state": "normal",
    "styling": {
        "link_color": "#0077CC",
        "tag_foreground_color": "#3E6D8E",
        "tag_background_color": "#E0EAF1"
    },
    "launch_date": 1221436800,
    "favicon_url": "//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico",
    "related_sites": [
        {
            "name": "Stack Overflow Chat",
            "site_url": "http://chat.stackoverflow.com",
            "relation": "chat"
        }
    ],
    "markdown_extensions": [
        "Prettify"
    ],
    "high_resolution_icon_url": "//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png"
}
```

as you can see:

```
"logo_url": "//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/logo.png"
"icon_url": "//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png"
"favicon_url": "//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico"
"high_resolution_icon_url": "//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png"
```

useless to say that I've got like tons of MalformedUrlException! :p

Hope you're going to fix this soon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was some monkeying around on the backend with URI generation, it's settled down now and this issue was resolved.